# Laravel eloquent - manyToMany, multiple "roles" on sigle pivot table

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

I have two models `User` and `Businesses`.

Business can have many Users and also the Business can have many Users.

For example:

- John is an admin for Business1.
- John is a superadmin for Business2.
- Mike is a customer for Business1.
- Mike is a subscriber for Business1.

What's the best way to connect these and query them later.

I built a pivot table `business_user` and added pivot columns

```
        $table->boolean('superadmin')->default(false);
        $table->boolean('admin')->default(false);
        $table->boolean('customer')->default(false);
        $table->boolean('subscriber')->default(false);
```

Is this the way to go or should I do it differently? Only other thing that comes up is different pivot tables for each of type of the relation but it seems like a bad idea.

I would query these as:

```
      $user->businesses()->wherePivot('subscriber',true)->get();
```

I hope I didn't miss the syntax anywhere, but if I did please correct me because of others.

There's also `Redis` as a next step.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution works fine, but to enable some more flexiblity later on (adding more roles, defining more relations to roles such as permissions, etc.), you could consider the following (watch out, this also introduces a little bit of complexity, so consider if you need this flexibility).

Create a dedicated model for the relation (`RoleAssignment`) and also have a model for the different roles (`Role`). Then, the RoleAssignment has three `belongsTo` relations, to `Role`, `User`, and `Business`:

```
class RoleAssignment extends Model {
    public function role() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
    }
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
    public function business() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Business::class);
    }
}

class Role extends Model {
    public function roleAssignments() {
        return $this->hasMany(RoleAssignment::class);
    }
}

class User extends Model {
    public function roleAssignments() {
        return $this->hasMany(RoleAssignment::class);
    }
    public function businesses($roleName = null) {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Business::class, RoleAssignment::class)->where('name';
    }
}

class Business extends Model {
    public function roleAssignments() {
        return $this->hasMany(RoleAssignment::class);
    }
}
```

The query that you gave, could then be written as:

```
$user->roleAssignments()->whereHas('role', function ($query) {
    return $query->where('name', 'subscriber');
})->with('business')->get()->pluck('business');
```

To simplify this a bit, you could modify your `roleAssignments` relation on the `User` model to accept an optional role name:

```
class User extends Model {
    public function roleAssignments($roleName = null) {
        $relation = $this->hasMany(RoleAssignment::class);
        if ($relation) {
            $relation->whereHas('role', function ($query) {
                return $query->where('name', 'subscriber');
            });
        }
        return $relation;
    }
}
```

Now you can write this query:

```
$user->roleAssignments('subscriber')->with('business')->get()->pluck('business');
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I don't need that much flexibility but I'll need custom permissions (Subscriber cant do same things to business as Admin can and similar). However, I think it's easily doable with my setup.
I will study your example more throughly as it is something I will surly need in the future.